# C problem: Passing var defined in function stack

Tags: c

```
int myfunc2(struct MyStruct st2[])
{ 

   return 0;

}

int myfunc() 
{
   struct MyStruct st;
   myfunc2(&st);
   return 0;
}
```

Is this a pure bug? Or it is not a bug if it didn't call another function and st is not passed to another function in myfunc2.  Can the st be the same one referenced by myfunc2 when myfunc2 get the pointer and pass it to another function?

Comment: `st` and `St` are different.  Do you have a typo or do you have `st` defined somewhere?

Comment: What is the problem here? Are you getting some unexpected results?

Comment: Why would you think it's a bug? Looks like perfectly valid code to me. I assume you meant to define the variable as "st", not "St", though, otherwise it's just a compile-time error.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here, or why you think this is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly valid code. You can pass it to any number of functions from `myfunc2`. The variable you allocated on stack will remain valid until it goes out of scope from `myfunc`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether MyStruct is defined at a scope visible to myfunc2() or not, and what parameter myfunc2() is expecting.

Edit: with your edit to include a function prototype, it is certainly perfectly valid code.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with passing the address of a local variable to a function, but remember that the variable goes out of scope (and the pointer ceases to be valid) when the containing function returns.  Be careful if `myfunc2()` might save the pointer for later use.

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed is valid if you used `myfunc2` in the correct way. You need to tell us the semantics (or show the implementation) of `myfunc2` in order to let us say if anything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the address of a local variable instead of an array is perfectly fine and equivalent to passing an array of size 1.

The problem with your code, however, is that myfunc2() has no way of knowing the size of the array passed to it. I guess it's okay if it uses only the first element of array, but then it should probably be declared to accept a pointer, not an array.

Comment: It's the problem. The function uses not only the first element of the array. I think I find what the problem is.